# iOS 11 firebase crash while getting the FCM TOKEN

Tags: firebase, swift4, ios11, firebase-notifications

I’m facing a real weird, struggling and non common error with firebase.

I implemented firebase for using dynamic’s link’s and push notifications services, In my devices, when I install the application, everything work perfectly, the FCM notification appears asking if I want to receive notifications and so on, everything’s good, my application opens the dynamic link and i can continue with the main flow…but..when a external user download my app (From testflight) and try to register, it even can move the slider that the app have, showing important information to the user…For me, it was so strange, when I start debugging I notice that the firebase configuration crashes in some devices…not all devices, just in some devices, its totally weird, I got the error from Xcode:

> 2018-03-09 11:15:29.791075-0800 [576:166962] TIC TCP Conn Failed
>   [3:0x1c017b3c0]: 12:8 Err(-65554) 2018-03-09 11:15:29.797689-0800
>   [576:166913] Task          <4FEC7052-68C6-4AB4-9D28-D2948C86D95B>.<2> 
>   HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [12:8]) 2018-03-09
>   11:15:29.798539-0800 [576:166963] Task
>   <4FEC7052-68C6-4AB4-9D28-D2948C86D95B>.<2> finished with error -
>   code: -1003 2018-03-09 11:15:35.381234-0800 [576:166980] Task
>   <306AF6B3-1502-4C6C-BA9C-7050EE81DCDD>.<1> finished with error -
>   code: -1001 2018-03-09 11:15:35.385275-0800 [576:166962] Task
>   <306AF6B3-1502-4C6C-BA9C-7050EE81DCDD>.<1> HTTP load failed (error
>   code: -999 [1:89]) iPhone detected: iPhone SE 2018-03-09
>   11:15:46.436282-0800 MyApp[576:166815] [MC] System group container
>   for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2018-03-09 11:15:46.436717-0800 [576:166815] [MC] Reading from public 
>   effective user settings. 2018-03-09 11:15:46.475048-0800 [576:166962] 
>   TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57 2018-03-09 11:15:46.475136-0800
>   [576:166962] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57 2018-03-09
>   11:15:55.143857-0800 [576:166939] XPC connection interrupted Message
>   from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

**When the application starts, I configure firebase to obtain the FCM token but, in some devices crash at that moment…I’m using swift 4 and iOS 11.2.6**

I don’t know if there’s a bug with firebase…Please let me know about this issue…My head its gonna explode!

Thanks for the help~

Comment: It says `Terminated due to memory issue`

Comment: Hi, I fixed it downgrading my current version of firebase pods to:

pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '2.0.0'
pod 'FirebaseInstanceID' , '2.0.0'

I don't know if firebase team have any idea about this but using iOS 11 or above are unstable due this conflict with firebase